# Javascript: How will this outputs to be 64 and 20?

Tags: javascript

How will this outputs to be 64 and 20?

I have got a question from one of my assessments and need to know the answer to that.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p id='test'></p>
<p id='test1'></p>
<script>
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = -"4"+10+"4";
    document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = "5"*3+5;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

With **`-"4"+10+"4";`** => `-"4"+10` is `6` and it is concatenated with `4` hence `64`

With **`"5"*3+5;`** => `"5"*3` is `15` and `5` is added to it hence `20`

Important things to consider here are:

- [**Unary negation (-)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_negation_(-)) attempts to convert it into a `number`, if it isn't already.

Comment: @AndrewL. — Updated...